# PHP - Adding line to textfile overwrites old lines.Also weird s: characters in textfile?

Tags: php, fwrite

What is the best way for adding a line to a textfile? When I run the below code, it overwrites all lines.

Also when adding a line it contains some "s:4:" & s:60: characters. What does this mean? I just want to add the `$photourl` to `urls.txt`.

```
<?php
  foreach ($_POST['photoselect'] as $photourl) {
   file_put_contents($target_dir . '/urls.txt', $photourl);
   $fp = fopen($target_dir . '/urls.txt','w'); 
   fwrite($fp,serialize($photourl));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you read the manual? It explains it all. You're writing to the file in two different ways, and `serialize()` causes the "s:n" things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append with file_put_contents
`file_put_contents($target_dir . '/urls.txt', $photourl, FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 1):

When opening a file, the last parameter indicates how you want the file pointer to be set.  With 'w', this truncates the file, you probably want to have 'a' which means put the pointer at the end of the file. ( see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php  modes )

Unless you content contains special characters, just write it and not `serialize` it.

Your code also overwrites the file each time...

```
$fp = fopen($target_dir . '/urls.txt','a'); 
foreach ($_POST['photoselect'] as $photourl) {
     fwrite($fp,$photourl.PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($fp);
```